# Access Token is not generating when extending User and Access Token Model - Loopback 3

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I am new to loopback. So as a part of the learning process, started creating a sample API. Also extended User model as Customer and AccessToken as CustomerAccessToken. But the problem is that access token is not being generated, when we tried to login data that is already send using a POST request.

Response body when login using credentials:

```
{
  "id": "oiMDjErGGVkeSMtnt1SfHzGuERZf6OCId5FUulvir6A04htUbIV656FOBlXn9vDS",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2019-05-09T09:41:05.184Z",
  "userId": "5cd3f59594d45186b411bb02"
}
```

No accessToken is generated. I have removed the inbuilt User and AccessToken model and used extended ones.

**model-config.json**

```
{
  "CustomerAccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  }
  "Customer": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

**customer.json**

```
"relations": {
    "accessTokens": { 
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CustomerAccessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": true
      }
    }
  }
```

**customerAccessToken.json**

```
{
  "name": "CustomerAccessToken",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

One more query: Will login functionality work, when we try to extend User & AccessToken models or Do I need to write login functionality in the customer.js file in order to make it work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to extend AccessToken, just the User model. If you need to extend the base AccessToken model, you can check [the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html#access-control-with-a-single-user-model) how to do that.

Comment: @akkonrad Thanks for the reply. I tried the same as per the doc. But when i try to get the users data using GET request, its showing 403 Authorization Error. Any suggestion for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the DEBUG variable to get more details about the error. from loopback root call

```
export DEBUG=loopback:security:access-context
npm start
```

to run the server in the debug mode. Then you can check what exactly is going on - which method is called and why you don't have access. 
Probably it's ACL setting: by default, you cannot get users data in loopback, so you may want to add ACL rule to the Customer entity. I suggest to use [loopback-cli](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installation.html) for that - it's less error-prone. Then you select a model where you want to add a new rule and following the step-by-step instruction. You can read more about ACL [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `CustomerAccessToken` unless you want to implement multiple user models.

This is the configuration that works great for me:

**model-config.json**

```js
{
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false,
    "relations": {
      "Customer": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "Customer",
        "foreignKey": "userId"
      }
    }
  },
  "Customer": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```js
app.use(loopback.token({
  model: app.models.accessToken,
  currentUserLiteral: 'me'
}))
```

Customer model must extend the User model:

**customer.json**

```js
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "plural": "customers",
  "base": "User"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Antonio Trapanis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073422/1244727) response. If you want to use your own AccessToken model to have to set it in `server.js`

```js
app.use(loopback.token({
  model: app.models.CustomerAccessToken,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial.
https://youtu.be/Jx39u8IssRg
I received *Token* in response body when logged in with 'user' through user controller.
I am able to to hit the end points of to-do model by passing that '*token*' in the headers as 'Bearer Token'. I used "**postman**" to hit the to-do end points 
( I was unable to insert/attach the received token into the to-do requests of loopback4 app)